# Basic Questions About Database Development

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio

I searched for the answers to these questions before, but couldn't find them - so I apologize if they have been answered already, or appear stupid. I am new to learning about databases, and am pretty confused.

I am helping someone who wants to build a website with a database. It is supposed to have secure html links, secure password and username inputs, and relatively low bandwidth use. It will also handle financial transactions, and should work with Paypal.

1. My partner is familiar with Visual Studio. Can the .net framework produce anything other than asp pages (like html or other language formats), or is every webpage produced a .asp?
2. How is Visual Studio for working with MySQL?
3. If the answer to #2 is terrible, then I was thinking of using PHPMyAdmin with MySQL. How is this for secure front-ends? Would this allow me to easily interface with a MySQL backend? Would this be my best bet considering #1? Or should I take a look at other programs/frameworks?
4. Are there any programs that help with back-end work, or does it all have to be coded by hand? If there are any, does anyone have recommendations considering the above? Would PHPMyAdmin, Microsoft SQL Server, or Xataface have a GUI to help do any back-end work?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

> My partner is familiar with Visual Studio. Can the .net framework
>   produce anything other than asp pages (like html or other language
>   formats), or is every webpage produced a .asp?

ASP.NET produces HTML. The pages may have the `aspx` extension as opposed to `.html` but they stuff rendered is regular HTML. You can use both, HTML controls and ASP.NET controls. Using ASP.NET controls offers some advantages but you don't have to if you don't want to.

> How is Visual Studio for working with MySQL?
>   If you are concerned about being able to connect from VS to a MySQL database without using other admin tools, then the answer is yes, [you can do it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-visual-studio-making-a-connection.html); however, VS is powerful for many more reasons than just this capability: like intellisense, a huge set of libraries at your disposal, powerful controls out of the box, etc.
>
> If the answer to #2 is terrible, then I was thinking of using
>   PHPMyAdmin with MySQL. How is this for secure front-ends? Would this
>   allow me to easily interface with a MySQL backend? Would this be my
>   best bet considering #1? Or should I take a look at other
>   programs/frameworks?

PHPMyAdmin is a tool for interfacing with MySQL; it allows you to run queries, create databases, tables, etc. but it won't help you creating "secure front-ends" per se. There are many tools available that sort of do the same PHPMyAdmin does; one of them is [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). As far as security, you can build secure websites pretty much using any kind of database; it really amounts more to how you design and program your application than any feature offered by any tool.

> Are there any programs that help with back-end work, or does it all have to be coded by hand? If there are any, does anyone have recommendations considering the above? Would PHPMyAdmin, Microsoft SQL Server, or Xataface have a GUI to help do any back-end work?

As far as MS SQL Server is concerned, you can use SQL Server Management Studio. You can create Databases, tables, stored procs, functions, indexes, views, users, etc, etc. from there and it offers intellisense when you connect to a MS SQL Server 2008 DB or greater version.